# Conditional loading content based on category id magento for product page

Tags: magento

I want to conditionally load content based on category id in product page but can't get it to work. I know I can do this by calling a custom attribute but this is not what I have in mind because the content is specifically for a particular category so I don't want to enter it repeatedly in each product for the given category.

Basically I was looking for something like this:

```
<?php if ($_catid = $this->getCategoryid('3')):?>
display content for category id 3 (content is entered directly in the view.phtml file)
<?php else: ?>
content for other cateogegory
<?php endif; ?>
```

Your guidance is greatly appreciate!

Update for the correct code (thanks ahadley):

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
<?php if($category->getId()==3): ?>

<h3>Show content for Category ID3</h3>

<?php else: ?>

<h3>Show content for other categories</h3>
<p>consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like the following to load the category:

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
```

Then you could get information such as:

```
 <?php echo $category->getName();?>
```

Comment: Thank you also, but I don't see how I can target the content (just plain html content) I want to show for Cat ID. This method seems only allow me to load the existing attribute/element of the current category.

Comment: It is perhaps a little overblown. It would allow you to get attributes for the category. So `->getId()` or similar could be used in a conditional.  `if($category->getName()=="test") do this;` or `if(($category->getId()==5) do this;` that sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you again for further info. I figured it now. Hoping this will help others too I am posting the complete code in my question instead.

Comment: Due to design issue, I realized the above isn't the best way because it limits to a given block (though this can be fixed but not pretty) so I have another question hoping I can do it real quick without touching too much CSS code: I want to target cat ID 3 for a block, than another cat ID (e.g, 4) for another block, so I removed  `<?php else: ?> ` using  `<?php if($category->getId()==3): ?><h3>Show content for Category ID3</h3><?php endif; ?> ` and  `<?php if($category->getId()==4): ?>=<h3>content for Category ID 4</h3><?php endif; ?> `. But this removes all the content in the given category.

Comment: I got it working by keeping `<?php else: ?>` and empty the content after it. In order for another targeted cat id's content to show up, I needed to revert the content order for another id and can only target one ID, example:     `<?php if($category->getId()==4): ?>   
 content for id 4
    <?php else: ?> 
   // keep it empty so that nothing show up in id 3
   <?php endif;?>`
   `<?php if($category->getId()==4): ?>
 // keep it empty so that nothing show up in id 4
 <?php else: ?>             
 content for id 3
  <?php endif;?> ` Not pretty!

Comment: Can't you use an `elseif` instead? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your `product/view.phtml` template:

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_category') == 3): ?>
// display content for category with the ID 3
<?php else: ?>
// content for other categories
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it only exclude the content in ID 3.

Comment: What would you exactly like to do? What is wrong with my answer? I do not get your point...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I tested your code again by targeting different cat id & now believe the code isn't working.  Content targeted in the specific ID (e.g. 3) doesn't showed up. Only the content after <?php else: ?> show regardless of products in any category (including the targeted category-and the first time it gave me false impression that the code works and excluded the content in the targeted category). I am using v1.6, not sure if this is the reason!?

Answer (score 0):

This is final code, and working fine.

```
 <?php if (Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 290) { ?>
    <?php 
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();                         
         $m = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load($categoryIds[0])
                ->getParentCategory();
            echo $m->getName();
    ?>
    <?php } else ?>
    <?php if (Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 202) { ?>
    <?php 
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();                         
         $m = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load($categoryIds[2])
                ->getParentCategory();
            echo $m->getName();
    ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php 
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();                         
         $m = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load($categoryIds[1])
                ->getParentCategory();
            echo $m->getName();
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
```