# Magento - Conditionally Display Attribute Based on Product Category

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to display an attribute ('release') if a product has a certain category ID. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
<?php if($category->getId() == 2): ?>
<h5 style="color:#f26522" >
<?php echo $_product->getData('release') ?></h5>
<?php else: ?>
```

This works well, but only allows me to limit to products categorized under the default category, in this case 'Id() == 2'.

I am trying to limit the function to display only for a subcategory of this root category, but it does not respond to its corresponding category ID.

How can this be accomplished? All help is appreciated!

For reference: [Conditional loading content based on category id magento for product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510007/conditional-loading-content-based-on-category-id-magento-for-product-page)

**Edit for Solution:**

```
<?php
  $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
  if(in_array(20,$categoryIds)):
?>
<h5 style="color:#f26522" ><b>
<?php echo $_product->getData('release'); ?></h5></b>
<?php endif;    ?>
```

Thanks to @R.S and @ndlinh for their input and support.

Special thanks to @programmer_rkt whose response [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16621/changing-display-according-to-product-category) helped clarify this concept.

For Further Reference: [Changing Display According to Product Category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16621/changing-display-according-to-product-category)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento category ID from product ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413565/magento-category-id-from-product-id)

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($product->getId()) {
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (is_array($categoryIds) && in_array(2 , $categoryIds)
      ...
      echo $_product->getData('release')
      ...
```

*Assuming that you are on the product detail page*

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
<?php 
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
    $parentIds = $category->getParentIds();
?>
<?php if(in_array(2, $parentIds): ?>
    <h5 style="color:#f26522" >
    <?php echo $_product->getData('release') ?></h5>
<?php else: ?>
```